# run multiples testcases in c++ by a file

Tags: c++

I have a file with 100000 testcases and I want to run it in onetime. How to do it?
This is my main file.

```
int readFile(string filename, int& HP1, int& HP2, int& EXP1, int& EXP2, int& M1, int& M2, int& E1, int& E2, int& E3) {
   ifstream myfile(filename);
   if (myfile.is_open()) {
       myfile >> HP1 >> HP2;
       myfile >> EXP1 >> EXP2;
       myfile >> M1 >> M2;
       myfile >> E1 >> E2 >> E3;
       return 1;
   }
   else return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   string filename = "input.txt";
   int HP1 = -1, HP2 = -1;
   int EXP1 = -1, EXP2 = -1;
   int M1 = -1, M2 = -1;
   int E1 = -1, E2 = -1, E3 = -1;
   bool isRead = readFile(filename, HP1, HP2, EXP1, EXP2, M1, M2, E1, E2, E3);
   if (isRead){
       
       //Task 1
       cout << firstMeet(EXP1, EXP2, E1) << endl;
       cout << EXP1 << " "<< EXP2 << endl;
       //Task 2
       cout << investigateScene(EXP1, EXP2, HP2, M2, E2)<< endl;
       cout << EXP1 << " "<< EXP2 << " " << HP2 << " " << M2 << endl;
       //Task 3
       cout << traceLuggage(HP1, EXP1, M1, E3)<< endl;
       cout << HP1 << " "<< EXP1 << " " << M1 << endl;
   }
   else{
       cout << "Cannot read input file";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

and I have an input file which contains 100000 cases with different inputs. How to run it in onetime .This is my testcases file.

```
Testcase input #1:
574 269
387 273
1441 841
577 260 275

Testcase input #2:
920 271
688 172
842 360
780 1972 730

Testcase input #3:
892 470
838 746
1216 1145
779 1776 1606

Testcase input #4:
431 608
233 211
835 412
62 573 1779

Testcase input #5:
412 457
570 427
591 1457
354 171 451
```

how to run this file in only onetime.

Comment: I don't know onetime. I tried to Google it, but too many hits. Is it a scripting language?

Comment: I have finished the code but I just want to sure if I were right or not :((